# How can I add a hashtable as value to an other Hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

I have the following method which returns a hashtable:

```
public static Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>> BuildIndex(List<Integer> configuration, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>> final_nGram = new Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>>();

    Hashtable<Integer, List<String>> tmp_nGram = new Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>();

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        String unparsed = inFile.nextLine().intern();
        String[] parsed = unparsed.split("\n");//change line
        sentences.add(parsed[0]);
    }
    inFile.close();
    int line = 0;        
    for (String s : sentences) {
        //for test
        //System.out.println(s);
        for (int x = configuration.get(0); x <= configuration.get(1); x++) {
            tmp_nGram.put(x, ngrams(x, s));
        }

        final_nGram.put(line, tmp_nGram);   

        line++;
    }

    return final_nGram;
}
```

ngrams(x, s) returns a List String>.

When I run it I get only the 1st sentence of the loop as key in final_nGram Hashtable. But I should get all sentences.

Actually what i am trying to do is save the hashtable tmp_nGram as value to another hashtable final_nGram.

Can someone explain me what is going wrong?

Comment: The scope of `tmp_nGram` should really be inside the `for` loop. Create a new instance for each iteration. Otherwise, each iteration might override entries added before.

Comment: yes, it worked!! I just kill tmp_nGram in each iteration. tmp_nGram=null; and I create new instance for each loop as you suggested! Thanx!